# remove add to cart button

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart

How to remove "add to cart" button if the product have attribute "haveAttribute" turn on in the mini cart from code below:

```
<?php

$wishlistHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');

?>

<?php if ($wishlistHelper->isAllow()) : ?>

<div class="mini-list" data-bind="scope: 'wishlist'">

    <div class="block-top">

        <div class="block-title">

            <strong><?php echo __('Your Wish List') ?></strong>

            <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->

            <span> - </span><span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter"></span>

            <a class="details md-icon-button launch md-ink-ripple" href="<?php echo $wishlistHelper->getListUrl() ?>"></a>

            <!-- /ko -->

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- ko ifnot: wishlist().counter -->

    <div class="block-content" layout-padding>

        <p class="empty"><?php echo __('You have no item in your wish list.') ?>

    </div>

    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: wishlist().counter -->

    <div class="block-content">

        <ul class="product-items" data-bind="foreach: wishlist().items, css: {'no-display': null}">

            <li class="item product-item">

                <div class="product-item-info row" style="width: 100%">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 product-item-left">

                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: product_url }" class="product-item-image">

                            <img data-bind="attr: { src: image.src, alt: image.alt}" class="img-responsive" />

                        </a>

                        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-post': delete_item_params}" class="md-icon-button btn-remove action delete"></a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="product-item-details col-xs-18 row">

                        <div class="col-xs-14">

                            <strong class="product-item-name">

                                <a data-bind="attr: { href: product_url }" class="product-item-link">

                                    <span><!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko --></span>

                                </a>

                            </strong>

                            <div class="product-item-price" data-bind="html: product_price"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-10">

                            <!-- ko if: product_is_saleable_and_visible -->

                            <div class="product-item-actions">

                                <div class="actions-primary">

                                    <form method="POST" data-bind="attr: {action: JSON.parse(add_to_cart_params).action}">

                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>

                                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: {value: JSON.parse(add_to_cart_params).data.item}" name="item" />

                                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: {value: JSON.parse(add_to_cart_params).data.uenc}" name="uenc" />

                                        <div class="qty-box">

                                            <label><?php echo __('Qty'); ?></label>

                                            <input class="wl-item-qty md-input" data-bind="attr: {value: parseInt(JSON.parse(add_to_cart_params).data.qty)}" type="text" name="qty" />

                                        </div>

                                        <button title="<?php echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" type="submit" class="tocart"></button>

                                    </form>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- /ko -->

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- /ko -->

</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
<!-- ko if: product_is_saleable_and_visible && !product().haveAttribute -->
```

Instead of this

```
<!-- ko if: product_is_saleable_and_visible -->
```